# iOS 9-Sharing via mail in UIActivity View Controller not Working

Tags: uiactivityviewcontroller, xcode7, ios9

Whenever I am clicking on the mail option in UIActivity View Controller for sharing purposes, the controller just dismisses itself. In iOS 8, its working like a charm but having issues in iOS 9. Any fix(s) ?

Answer (score 0):

That issue does not happen on the device but only in the simulator. But it is quite misleading since the function used to worked in simulator before iOS9.